# .bat reading variables as "ECHO IS OFF"

Tags: batch-file

I've used the following pice of code in a program off mine and it simply says "echo is off" instead of the typed name.

```
set /p set QuizName =Quizname:
echo %QuizName%
echo %QuizName% >> Quiz.txt
pause
```

Comment: Um, `set /p set` doesn't do what you think. Meanwhile, the ECHO command prints ECHO IS (on/off) if you pass an empty command line. Now connect the dots.

Comment: Oh... what would you suggest as a replacement for set /p set

Comment: @callumgilchrist See my answer.

Comment: yay, fixed it thank you i manged to type set twice

Comment: @callumgilchrist And the trailing space counts as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### It simply says "echo is off" instead of the typed name.

> set /p set QuizName =Quizname:

The `echo` fails because `%QuizName%` is not defined. The above line of code creates a variable named "set QuizName " (note the "set" and the spaces).

Here is the syntax for the `set` command:

```
Syntax
      SET variable
      SET variable=string
      SET /A "variable=expression"
      SET "variable="
      SET /P variable=[promptString]
      SET "
```

Source [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

Corrected batch file:

```
set /p QuizName=Quizname:
echo %QuizName%
echo %QuizName% >> Quiz.txt
pause
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.